Can I get my texture coordinates as pixel coords in 2D Game?
I have an issue with my 2D Game in C++/OpenGL.
I need to somehow get the pixel coordinates (preferably the glfw coords) of a texture that has been rendered on the screen. The final goal is to be able to click on a texture in the window and get the correct texture name. To be able to perform per pixel collision with the mouse click, I need to know where exactly the texture is located in the window.
However, I am super confused about the various coordinate systems and how to get to the coord form I am looking for.
Can anyone help me on how to get started on this, or did someone maybe even have the same issue as me?
Now to the facts:
This is my mvp matrix:
glm::mat4 Game::calculateMvpMatrix(glm::vec3 position, float zRotationInDegrees, glm::vec3 scale){
        glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        model = glm::translate(model, position);
        model = glm::scale(model, scale);
        model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(zRotationInDegrees), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

        glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 90.0f),
                                     glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
                                     glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

        int windowWidth, windowHeight;
        glfwGetWindowSize(window, &windowWidth, &windowHeight);
        glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, 8.0f, 0.0f, 4.5f, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        return projection * view * model; }

This is how I use it in the shader:
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos; ...
uniform mat4 mvp;

void main() {
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(aPos, 1.0); ...

Then I have the vertex positions of the texture in my Renderer:
        data.vertexPositions[0] = {0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
        data.vertexPositions[1] = {-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
        data.vertexPositions[2] = {-0.5f, 0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f};
        data.vertexPositions[3] = {0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f};

which I then transform in my Renderer:
 void BatchRenderer::DrawQuad(const glm::vec3& position, float rotation, const glm::vec2& size, unsigned int textureID,
                                 const glm::vec4& texColor, float texAlpha)
    { 
        ...

        glm::mat4 transform = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), {position.x, position.y, 0.0f}) *
                              glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::radians(rotation), {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}) *
                              glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), {size.x, size.y, 1.0f});

        data.quadBufferPtr->Position = transform * data.vertexPositions[0];
        data.quadBufferPtr->Color = texColor;
        data.quadBufferPtr->TexCoords = {0.0f, 0.0f};
        data.quadBufferPtr->TexID = texIndex;
        data.quadBufferPtr->TexAlpha = texAlpha;
        data.quadBufferPtr++;
        
        ...

Does anybody know how I can get the glfw pixel coordinates or even just normalized screen coordinates out of these information?

gluProject - map object coordinates to window coordinates; gluUnProject - map window coordinates to object coordinates. Note: have a look at the Description sections, they show how these operations could be (are) implemented, use them as example. As far as i know, glm also has project/unproject operations.

@ErdalKüçük thanks so much for the hint! I‘ll try and see if I can get it to work with that :)
